# Swift - how to hide unknown button?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have 4 buttons. Each of them represent 1 answer for question in trivia game. In different screens i have different questions and buttons with different answers. I have a mode, when when player can make a mistake, this is enabled by pressing the fifth button. So, when this mode is enabled i show alert and i need to hide button with wrong question which was pressed. Everything that i know about - that it is member of array with buttons with wrong questions. How can I tell the alert which button to hide on completion ?

Answer (score 2):

Attach them all to an IBAction that takes a UIButton and then hide the one that was pushed by adding the line

```
sender.hidden = true
```

or disable it by adding

```
sender.enabled = false
```

Comment: i tried solution with sender and understood that i messed up with description if problem, so i updated it. Or solution with sender is still right and i do something wrong ?

Comment: I set tag to button and alert so from alert tag property i get know that which button is pressed.

Comment: @AlexeyK I would probably personally do it all within the action, alert and disabling/hiding both, using an if statement to check if it's in your array/not the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you wish to know if the button has been pressed? Well if you connect that UIButton to that IBAction, that IBAction will be fired each time the button is pressed. You could insert and NSLog("button press") line inside the IBAction to see that it is pressed.